# Blazor in .NET 8: Routing issue when load Page from Razor Class Library

Tags: c#, routes, blazor, .net-8.0, razor-class-library

I am currently encountering a routing issue in my new `.NET 8 Blazor` project. When attempting to navigate to a page defined in a Razor class library, I encounter a **404 error**.

The Razor class library has already been properly referenced in the Blazor web application, and the `Routes.razor` file has been configured accordingly:

```
<Router AppAssembly="@typeof(Program).Assembly"
        AdditionalAssemblies="new[]{
                                    typeof(PostsPage).Assembly // Razor class library reference
                                   }">
    <Found Context="routeData">
        <RouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(Layout.MainLayout)" />
        <FocusOnNavigate RouteData="@routeData" Selector="h1" />
    </Found>
    <NotFound>
        <LayoutView Layout="@typeof(Layout.MainLayout)">
            <p>Sorry, there's nothing at this address.</p>
        </LayoutView>
    </NotFound>
</Router>
```

I am facing the same issue after upgrading an existing .NET 7 project to .NET 8. According to the upgrade documentation, no additional configurations are required when transitioning from .NET 7 to .NET 8.

Does anyone have an idea about the problem and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved the issue by call the "AddAdditionalAssemblies" method in the Program.cs class:

```
app.MapRazorComponents<App>()
    .AddAdditionalAssemblies(typeof(PostsPage).Assembly) // the solution
    .AddInteractiveServerRenderMode();

app.Run();
```

For more information, you can take a look at [this article](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/asp-net-core-updates-in-dotnet-8-rc-1/).